# Maximum area of triangle given fixed base and perimeter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I tried solving the question in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725950/maximum-area-of-quadrilateral-of-given-perimeter) in another way and got a different result,

> Let $0\lt a\lt b$
>
> **(i)** Show that among the triangles with base $a$ and perimeter $a + b$, the maximum area is obtained when the other two sides have equal length $b/2$.

My idea was to treat the side as vectors of same length, so $\vec{a}$ be one side and $ \vec{p}$ be an adjacent side, both vectors originating from the same point, then the maximum area occurs when both of them are perpendicular.  (Note: $\vec{a}$ represents the side of side length $a$

Proof: $ \vec{a} \times \vec{p} = |a| |p| \sin \theta$, expression is maximized at $ \theta  = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so this suggests the right angle at the common origin of $\vec{a} $ and $\vec{p}$

However, if this the case the perimeter condition can never be satisfied.. What went wrong here?

Comment: I see you already have an answer on why this does not work. One simple way to show it is by drawing an ellipse and using the fact that $d_1 + d_2 = 2a$ where $d_1, d_2$ are distances of a point on ellipse from two focii and $2a$ is major axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that the length of one side given by $\vec{p}$ is fixed, but that would give no further freedom as the length of the other side will also be fixed due to the perimeter constraint, and so the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec p$ is fixed. To do the problem, you need to assume exactly one degree of freedom - either $\theta$ or $|\vec p|$.

Comment: I mean suppose $|p|$ has whatever value, stil area should be maxed when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so I am having a hard time figuring out how I didn't account for degrees of freedom

Comment: @Buraian Yes, it should be. But then you are straight up ignoring the given constraint.

Comment: Oh right I get it now, the set of lengths of $p$ and the set angles between $p$ and $a$, the place where area is maximized with angle and the set where it is maximized with $p$ satisfying the constraint are not the same

Comment: @Buraian Yes, that’s another way to put it.

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed the length of vector $p$ or length of one side and now your other length side is fixed. What you can try is:

Let $BC=a$ and $AB+AC=b$. From Heron's formula,

$Δ=\sqrt{s(s−BC)(s−AB)(s−AC)}$

Since $s$ is given, we maximize $Δ=\sqrt{s(s−BC)(s−AB)(s−AC)}$. From AM-GM inequality, $Δ=\sqrt{s(s−BC)(s−AB)(s−AC)}<= \dfrac{s^\frac{3}{2}}{3 \sqrt {3}}$

For the equality to hold, $s−BC=s−AB=s−AC$ which shows $AB=AC=\frac{b}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first condition if we can use a property of the ellipse, it is that a + b is constant, the locus is an ellipse with A,B as foci.

For the second condition of area, it equals  $ \frac12 \cdot b \cdot y$ where $y$ is the height of triangle on base AB = $a$. Maximum $y$ should be on the perpendicular bisector.

It can also be seen that asymmetry points such as C decrease the area compared to its position at highest point at D, going to zero when C lies at the extremities of major axis.

So the point satisfying both criteria is D... so that each side of the isosceles triangle should equal $b/2$.

[image]