# the one with the greatest

Tags: geometry, triangles

Show that among all the triangles with base b and prefixed perimeter p, the one with the greatest area is the corresponding isosceles triangle.

As an idea to carry out this demonstration I have used Heron's formula

$$ A = \sqrt{s(s-l1)(s-l2)(s-b)} $$

where b is the base, and l1 and l2 the other sides of the triangle. And the goal is to prove that l1 = l2, but I can't get to the result.
Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Same as first question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173728/maximum-area-of-triangle-given-fixed-base-and-perimeter?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The locus for the third vertex is an ellipse with the base vertices as focal points. To maximise area, we have to maximise height …

Comment: Please do not answer problem statement questions for which you do the OPs work for them.  Particularly when it is a dupe.